# How can I split a string into only two parts with Perl?

Tags: perl, split

I have a string that with several parts separated by tabs:

```
 Hello\t2009-08-08\t1\t2009-08-09\t5\t2009-08-11\t15
```

I want to split it up only on the first tab, so that "Hello" ends up in `$k` and and rest ends up in `$v`. This doesn't quite work:

```
my ($k, $v) = split(/\t/, $string);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Actually, I just read the doc for split(), was baffled; googled, and came here.  Where I found the answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In order to get that, you need to use the 3rd parameter to [`split()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), which gives the function a maximum number of fields to split into (if positive):

```
my($first, $rest) = split(/\t/, $string, 2);
```

Comment: What if the value's length is uncertain, and I want to capture all of it in $v.  $v's format is going to look like date_1\tvalue_1\tdate_2\tvalue_2\tdate_3\tvalue_3...

Comment: This will capture "date_1" in $k, and "value_1\tdate_2\tvalue_2\tdate_3\tvalue_3..." in $v. For more information, I linked to the perldoc reference page on the `split()` function - it will explain how it works in all the detail you could ever want. I suggest you read it. Perldoc is very informative.

Answer (score 8):

No.  It will give you the first two items and toss the rest.  Try this:

```
my ($k, $v) = split(/\t/, $string, 2);
```

Comment: What if the value's length is uncertain, and I want to capture all of it in $v.  $v's format is going to look like date_1\tvalue_1\tdate_2\tvalue_2\tdate_3\tvalue_3...

Comment: Like Chris Lutz said in his comment, the number tells Perl how many parts to split into.  So, with a value of 2, the first part goes in $v, the first \t in consumed in the split, and the remainder of the string goes unaltered into $v.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a simple regex.

```
my($k,$v) = $str =~ /([^\t]+)\t(.+)/;
```